# How to check if calendar app installed in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I have added some buttons to my app in order to create intents for calendar events. But I think it would be better to check if the user has or not any calendar app. How could I do this?

Calendar intents look like:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");   
calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "My House Party");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Beach House");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "A Pig Roast on the Beach");

GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 7, 15);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
     calDate.getTimeInMillis());
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
     calDate.getTimeInMillis());

startActivity(calIntent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In section 3.2.3.1 of the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf), it says

> The Android upstream project defines a number of core applications, such as contacts, **calendar**, photo gallery, music player, and
>   so on. Device implementers MAY replace these applications with alternative versions.
>   However, any such alternative versions MUST honor the same Intent patterns provided by the upstream project. For example, if a
>   device contains an alternative music player, it must still honor the Intent pattern issued by third-party applications to pick a song.

The document goes on to list all core applications:

- Desk Clock
- Browser
- **Calendar**
- Contacts
- Gallery
- GlobalSearch
- Launcher
- Music
- Settings

This basically means that all devices with the Google Play Store will have a calendar app (as well as all the apps listed above) installed that honour the standard intent patterns. Therefore, you don't need to check at all.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't knew about these core applications. Just a question, maybe you can help me with it. I asked this question because the intent is crashing my app for any reason. I couldn't know and I don't know if there was a calendar app installed. What else could be crashing the app?

Comment: I haven't ever used the Calendar intents, actually, so I can't tell just by looking at your code. Try posting a separate question and include the error you get in LogCat (this will help me and others debug your code). You can link the new question here in the comments.

Comment: I cannot access the logcat because this is an issue a user is having with my app. He bought it in the Play Store and he told me the calendar intent was crashing the app :S

Comment: I believe the play store can collect bug reports, that may help too. Just ask your user to send a bug report when the app crashes.

Comment: Do I have to code something for those bug reports or they are just there and can be used?

Comment: No, I believe the user just has to press a button called "Report" on the dialog that appears when the app crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59753/discussion-between-musicmaster-and-user1903).

Answer (score 3):

As MusicMaster said, all Android devices should have a Calendar application. However if you're making an intent that you're not sure will be honored by any activities, you can query the package manager using your intent to see if there are any activities able to respond to it. Like this:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(yourIntent, 0);
```

If the size of `activities` is greater than zero, the user has an app that can respond to your Intent.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to check if an app is installed in android?

This is my method:

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

for example, if the app exists then start an intent:

```
   if(isPackageInstalled("com.android.calendar", getApplicationContext())){
        Intent i = new Intent();
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);
    }else{
        Log.i("myApp", "Application NOT Installed! :( ");
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for devices with the stock Android calendar? If the device is Samsung, HTC, etc., it will probably have a different calendar app with a different package name.

Comment: this is only an example the app package will change even with OS versions.